# Prevent elements in the DockPanel from expanding

Tags: wpf, dockpanel, horizontal-alignment

I have the following code where I want to prevent the first two buttons from expanding when the Expander is opened:

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Button Content="AAAAA" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <Button Content="AAAAA" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <Expander>
            <Button Content="AAAAAAAAAA" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        </Expander>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

I would appreciate help on how to do this in a clean way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening to you because **the default value of HorizontalAlignment is Stretch**.
Therefore, to achieve the result you asked for, you need to do this:

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Button Content="AAAAA" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Button Content="AAAAA" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Expander>
            <Button Content="AAAAAAAAAA" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        </Expander>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```